# mrjob in emr is running only 1 MRStep out of 3 MRSteps and cluster is shutting down

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, amazon-emr, mrjob

[image: The AWS CONSOLE emr terminated just after executing STEP 1 of mrjob]

[image: log of the first step in aws]

The error looks something like this :-
Terminating cluster: j-SDOP2KOKWYZM

botocore.exceptions.ClientError: An error occurred (ValidationException) when calling the AddJobFlowSteps operation: A job flow that is shutting down, terminated, or finished may not be modified.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Following the error. It is clear that the cluster is terminating after step 1.
This issue is because the `botocore` package is deprecated.

A solution to this could be:

1. Start a persistent cluster
2. Use that cluster ID to run the mr job in emr

Commands:

```sh
mrjob create-cluster
```

Make sure you have configured the cluster-info in `mrjob.config` file. The above command lets you create a persistent cluster.

```sh
python3 MovieSimilarities.py -r emr --cluster-id "your-cluster-id"
    --items=ml-100k/u.item ml-100k/u.data > sims2t.txt
```

Now specify the cluster id to run your cluster.